# Cocoa/ObjC: Place a floating window above a modal window

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have two NSWindows. Window A with level 0, and Window B with level 1. I'm using B as a floating window.

This works as expected until I put A as a modal window (i.e., send runModalForWindow:A message to NSApplication). Then B is always behind A.

Is there a way that I can have B above A, even when A is running as a modal window?

Much appreciated for the help.

Answer (score 2):

To put your floating window in front, use `[myfloater setLevel: NSModalPanelWindowLevel+1]`.

Other people are telling you that you will have trouble interacting with the floater, but I've done it and it worked for me.  (My floater uses `NSPanel` of "Utility Panel" style rather than plain `NSWindow`, but I'm not sure if that's important.  You may also need to say `[myPanel setWorksWhenModal: YES]`.)

Comment: Good! This solution solved my problem, "[myPanel setWorksWhenModal: YES]" is very important, that makes your floating panel can receive message when some other window is being run modally.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK that is not possible.

From the Apple class reference:

**NSApplication runModalForWindow:**

> This method runs a modal event loop for the specified window
>   synchronously. It displays the specified window, makes it key, starts
>   the run loop, and processes events for that window. (You do not need
>   to show the window yourself.) While the application is in that loop,
>   it does not respond to any other events (including mouse, keyboard, or
>   window-close events) unless they are associated with the window. It
>   also does not perform any tasks (such as firing timers) that are not
>   associated with the modal run loop. In other words, this method
>   consumes only enough CPU time to process events and dispatch them to
>   the action methods associated with the modal window.

Given this, your Window A will become the key window and will always be shown on top of any other window of your app. I think this is how modal windows are supposed to work.

As an alternative you can consider using an `NSPopover` which has a clear presence to the user but does not force your application into a modal state.

Check out [this page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/applehiguidelines/Windows/Windows.html) from the Apple docs on guidelines re various options available to you.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you set the window level to NSScreenSaverWindowLevel, it will always be on top.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `orderFront:`, `orderFrontRegardless`, or `orderFront:relativeTo:`, to have B moved in front of A. However not sure how many tasks can you do in B, as due to the fact that A is modal, you won't be able to interact with B.